# Ajax response parse Error

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, response

OK i am tring to figure out how to fix this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '968' in "[["Acura", "acura"], ["Alfa Romeo", "alfaromeo"], ["Aston Martin", "astonmartin"]]"
```

Console info for error:

```
isArraylike @   jquery.js?body=1:584 
jQuery.extend.each  @   jquery.js?body=1:359
$.ajax.complete @   new:922
jQuery.Callbacks.fire   @   jquery.js?body=1:3120
jQuery.Callbacks.self.fireWith  @   jquery.js?body=1:3232
done    @   jquery.js?body=1:9291
jQuery.ajaxTransport.send.callback  @   jquery.js?body=1:9686


isArraylike @   jquery.js?body=1:584

584:  typeof length === "number" && length > 0 && ( length - 1 ) in obj;
```

this is where my error is:

```
        complete: function(response) {
            response = response.responseText;
```

if i manually set response to the array it works:

```
 response = [["Ford","ford"],["Chevy", "chevy"]]
```

Controller:

```
  def make
    models = CarDetails.get_makes(params["year"])
    # models is an array that looks like: [["Ford","ford"],["Chevy", "chevy"]]
    render :text => models
  end
```

Function:

```
function getMakes(id, year) {
   var makes_id = id.replace("year", "make");
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/car/make",
        data: {
            'year': year
        },
        complete: function(response) {
            response = response.responseText;
            $("#" + makes_id).empty();
            $.each(response, function(index, value) {
               $("#" + makes_id).append("<option value='" + value[1] + "'>"+ value[0] +"<\/option>")
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: You're getting a string back, it's not JSON.

Comment: how can i convert it

Comment: If you were getting a valid JSON response, you could use `JSON.parse(response.responseText)`; But the response you're getting is just a string representation of a JSON array. Valid Jason must be encapsulated in a single object, like `{"cars":[["Ford","ford"],["Chevy", "chevy"]]}`;. So you need to modify the response from the server before parsing it. Or ask the server to provide a valid JSON response!